# Jmeter-Thread- how to run set of user at fixed interval of time

Tags: performance, jmeter

Hi i want to run a performance test in which i want to load say 10 users in first second and wait for 2 minutes then load next 10 set of users and again wait for 2 minutes then again 10 users in the same Test plan is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose "Stepping Thread Group" is the thing you need. And to fix or control the number of samples to execute you can use "Constant Throughput Timer".
Constant Throughput Timer will let you control the flow of requests to be sent."Stepping Thread Group" or default "Thread Group" only control the way the users or threads will be generated.It doesn't control the rate of requests to be hit your application.So for this purpose, you could use "**Constant Throughput Timer**" to control your requests per second.
For further detail, you could go through JMeter documentation.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer

Comment: Thanks @ Adnan i will look into it and reply

Comment: hi also plz let me know how to define number of iterations

Comment: Thread Groups under JMeter Plugins doesn't come up with iteration controlling, rather they provide "Duration" or "Hold load" option. But if you want to control the number of iteration I would recommend using "Loop Controller" under "Logic Controller" component. Otherwise, you could use default "Thread Group" and uncheck the loop count  "Forever" and put your desired value(How many times you need to iterate).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JMeter, then Stepping Thread Group is what you are looking for.

Features of Stepping thread group are :
1. preview graph showing estimated load 
2. initial thread group delay to combine several thread group activities
3. increase load by portions of threads (users) with ramp-up period
4. configurable hold time after all threads started
5. decrease load by portions

Following screenshot shows Stepping Thread Group set to generate load increasing by 10 users each 2 minutes:

[Stepping Thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQhGD.png)

If you plan to increase your user/thread at a constant rate, the Stepping Thread Group helps. You can read more about it at : 
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/

But if you plan to increase your load at a non-constant rate, for example, if your plan is --  start 10 threads in first 5 seconds, wait for 10 secs and start 5 threads, wait for 15 more secs and start 15 threads , then you can use Ultimate Thread Group.

I won't write more about Ultimate Thread Group, since I will limit myself to the question asked. If you are more interested about it, you can read it over at JMeter Plugins site.

Comment: Thanks @ Gayathri this is what i was looking for

Comment: hi can you help me how can i fix number of sample execution in above as i am not able to do that